# Is there a way to reset performance.now?

Tags: javascript, html

Hope you all having a good day!

I was requested to make a timer in javascript and I thought using `performance.now` would be a good idea, but when I try to reset the timer the timer stays where it stops instead of becoming zero.

```js
let time = performance.now();
function initInterval(){ 
  let taken = performance.now() - time;
  let current = (time += taken);
  setInterval(function () {
    // time calculation to make it easy to read, display 
    // and eventListener to stop, end of the function
  }
}
```

I want to reset the timer with a function call but it keeps giving me the same numbers before stopping the interval.

```js
function resetInterval(){
  closebutton.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    staticTimer.innerHTML = "00:00:00"
    initInterval()
    console.log('beep');
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to reset `performance.now()`. What you can do is to save current `performance.now()` when the timer starts and just substract it afterwards. Looking at your code, simply set ´time = performance.now()´ again and you are done.

Comment: I actually tried to substract it on the reset function but i just dont work after stop the interval.
But im gonna try again, thanks.
Would be good to know if there's a way to restart the whole script idk if that would work

Comment: @JoseMoreno you are setting `time = performance.now();` OUTSIDE init interval. You need to set it inside init interval so it is reset again. Keep in mind that `time` is the variable that has your offset each time the interval starts.

Comment: I'm glad @JoseMoreno :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `performance.now()` cannot be reset. The value which is returned is the elapsed time since [time origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp#The_time_origin)

Here is a simple implementation using js classes. I've saved the time since page load as a constant which I subtract from both `this.startTime` and `this.endTime` before returning the difference between them.

```js
class Timer {
    constructor() {
        this.startTime = undefined;
        this.endTime = undefined;
        this.constantTimeSincePageLoad = Math.trunc(performance.now());
    }
    endTimer() {
        if (!this.startTime) return 'please start the timer';
        this.endTime = Math.trunc(performance.now());
        this.constantTimeSincePageLoad = Math.trunc(performance.now());
        this.startTime -+ this.constantTimeSincePageLoad;
        this.endTime -+ this.constantTimeSincePageLoad;
        const result = this.endTime - this.startTime;
        this.startTime = undefined;
        this.endTime = undefined;
        return result;
    }
    startTimer() {
        this.startTime = Math.trunc(performance.now());
    }
}
const timer = new Timer();

// activate the timer
timer.startTimer();

// stop the timer - meant to show that the time is reset on each invocation
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(timer.endTimer());
}, 100)
```